# FadeIn one by one then FadeOut everything at once (loop) - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on animation, first I like to show div one by one once all the div done I need to fadeout all div with timeout, then I need to loop this function, I was tried with following code but loop is not happening. Someone please advice how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var divs = $("[id^=show]");
            var i = 0;
            var loop = window.setInterval(function () {
               
                $(divs[i]).fadeIn(1000); i++;
                if (i == divs.length)
                    clearInterval(loop);
            }, 1000);
        });
```

```css
 .divclass {
            height: 100px;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: green;
            border: 5px solid red;
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show1" class="divclass">show1</div> <br />
<div id="show2" class="divclass">show2</div> <br />
<div id="show3" class="divclass">show3</div> <br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. I added new `setTimeout` to hide all divs when finished all `fadeIn`s

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var divs = $("[id^=show]");
            var i = 0;
            var number_of_divs = divs.length;
            var totalTime = (number_of_divs * 1000);
            
            function run() {
            var loop = window.setInterval(function () {
               
             $(divs[i]).fadeIn(1000); i++;
                if (i == divs.length){
                i = 0;
                    clearInterval(loop);
              setTimeout(function(){
              $.when($(divs).fadeOut(1000)).done(run);
            }, totalTime);                  
                    }
               }, 1000);
            };

            

            run();
        });
```

```css
.divclass {
            height: 100px;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: green;
            border: 5px solid red;
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show1" class="divclass">show1</div> <br />
<div id="show2" class="divclass">show2</div> <br />
<div id="show3" class="divclass">show3</div> <br />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the loop function is not working. Can you help me to fix it

Comment: This is works as expected. Thank you so much!